# Does PHP exit() also close open result sets?

Tags: php

I like to close SQL result sets after I'm done using them with either `sqlsrv_cancel($result)` or `mysqli_free_result($result)` depending on the type of connection I'm using.

If I need to call `exit()` before I call either sqlsrv_cancel or mysqli_free_result is *$result* implicitly cleared from memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the looks of it: yes.

> Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically destroyed when a PHP script finishes its execution.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php

Calling `exit()` or `die()` stops PHP script execution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does close the connection and clears from memory, except if you've got a persistent database connection.

> Persistent connections are links that do not close when the execution of your script ends. When a persistent connection is requested, PHP checks if there's already an identical persistent connection (that remained open from earlier) - and if it exists, it uses it. If it does not exist, it creates the link. An 'identical' connection is a connection that was opened to the same host, with the same username and the same password (where applicable).

You can read more about it at http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php